# If $\sum_{i=1}^t(n_i-1)+1$ pigeons are distributed among $t$ pigeonholes, then there exists a pigeonhole that contains at least $n_i$ pigeons.

Tags: solution-verification, proof-writing, pigeonhole-principle

[Full exercise description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBxt7.png)

$Proof$.
Suppose that for each $i$ the pigeonhole $h_i$ contains at most $n_i-1$ pigeons. Then the total number of pigeons at most is $(n_1-1)+(n_2-1)+\cdots+(n_t-1)=\sum_{i=1}^t\left(n_i-1\right)<\sum_{i=1}^t\left(n_i-1\right)+1$.

Is my proof valid? Also, someone told me that if proving by contrapositive or contradiction, it should be stated, is this true? I have never heard anyone else say that before.

Comment: For such a short proof, it's not really crucial to mention you're proving by contradiction/contrapositive, but for longer more intricate proofs, it does become important to notify the reader what is happening. Imagine paragraphs of complicated argumentation, some of which are by contradiction, others not. It would be a mess to read. Also, your proof looks good.